# Incompatible results with double factorial different definitions

Tags: definition, factorial

Maybe this is a stupid question but I'm lost.

The double factorial is defined as:

$$n!!=\prod_{k=1}^\frac n2 2k=n\times(n-2)\times(n-4)\times\dots\times2$$

For $n$ even. By definition $0!!=1$ as an empty product (pretty similar to how $0!=1$) but then Wikipedia says that for an even integer the double factorial can be expressed as (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial under the complex argument section):

$$(2k)!!=2^kk!\sqrt \frac 2\pi$$

But how can this be ? The two definitions are different and if I put $k=0$, as an example, I get that:

$$0!!=\sqrt \frac 2\pi\neq1$$

Is that an error of Wikipedia ? If not how can I arrive to a definition different from my original one just manipulating terms ?

Comment: ??? Where is the $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ coming from? That doesn't even check out for non-zero examples. Ex. $4!! = 4\cdot 2 = 8 = 2^2 \cdot 2!$.

Comment: I added the Wikipedia (sig) page @LJL

Comment: I see, it comes from the section on complex arguments. I prefer mathworld as a resource: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

Comment: You skipped the sentence "Disregarding the above definition of n!! for even values of n": this is an alternative definition of the double factorial which relates it to the Gamma function and is more general. This is why $\sqrt\pi$ appears.

Comment: Yes but when I'm solving a problem and I get into double factorials what definition should I use ? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Context will tell you. If you are dealing with series or combinatorics, the simple definition holds. The other can appear in advanced calculus and the theory of complex variables.

Comment: The deal is, $!!$ can be thought of as _two_ functions — one for the odd numbers and one for the even ones. The article extended the one for the odd numbers.

Comment: @RenatoFaraone Since you seem to be creator of the new tag, I will point out [this post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/21289#21289). The same tag was previously discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17011/should-double-factorials-be-under-the-factorial-tag). I should say that I appreciate that you have also created tag-wiki and tag-excerpt. (Many user who create new tags neglect this.)

Answer (score 1):

The referred formula is an analytic continuation of the formula for odd integers, so it's not against the rules if it doesn't agree with the factual results in the even case! The situation is the same with the series:

$$1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots = - \frac{1}{12}$$

which, despite seeming "non-sense" at first glance, actually finds applications even in physics.

PS For ordinary computations (e.g. in combinatorics) you should use the ordinary formula.

Comment: Yes I know what analytic continuation is but shouldn't be the original definition still holds ? For example I think that you are referring to the Riemann's Zeta function. When it is continuated analytically through the whole complex plain the original definition still holds for complex numbers with $\Re(z)>1$ while dealing with double factorial this is not the case...

Comment: No, analytic continuations don't always agree with each other - they depend on the boundary, from where the continuation starts. $z!!$ is an example of this - its the analytic continuation for even $z$ is $z!! = \sqrt{2}^z \Gamma \left( \frac{z}{2}+1 \right)$, which is not the same as the one for odd $z$.

Comment: But isn't an analytic continuation which do even agree with the original function definition a better one? Isn't it sufficient ?@Bundarenko